# Use yup to validate json content with conditional logic

Tags: javascript, api, validation, yup

I try to validate the following JSON:

```
  "flight": true,
  "hotel": false,
  "car": false,
   "flightReservation": {
    "type": "depart-return",
    "flights": [
      {
        "fromTown": "Paris",
        "toTown": "Barcelona",
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

using conditional logic. The  "flightReservation" is required only if the "flight" is true.

I use the following yup schema to try the validation:

```
const yup = require("yup");

const flightsSchema = yup.object({
  fromTown: yup.string().required(),
  toTown: yup.string().required()
});

const flightReservationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  type: yup.string(),
  flights: yup.array().of(flightsSchema),
});

const reservationSchema = yup.object({
  flight: yup.boolean().required(),
  hotel: yup.boolean().required(),
  car: yup.boolean().required(),
  flightReservation: flightReservationSchema.when("flight", {
    is: true,
    then: flightReservationSchema.required(),
  }),
});

module.exports = reservationSchema;
```

but it don't work , i can send the json even without the "flightReservation" object. If I change the "flightReservation" to a string instead of object, for example

```
flightReservation: yup.string().when("flight", {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required(),
  }),
```

it work well , I can't send the JSON with the "flight":true without a "flightReservation".

Thank you !